# Make a variable from what's in a text file

Tags: python, variables

So I want to make a variable from the contents of a text file.

E.g
The text file contains the sentence "Ask not what your country can do for you ask what you can do for your country"

Now I want the variable to be a string which contains the sentence in text file:
Sentence = ("Ask not what your country can do for you ask what you can do for your country")

But import the string value from the text file, if that makes any sense?

Comment: The documentation has you covered on that.  If you have problems, please show what you've tried https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: "_Now I want the variable to be like Sentence_" What do you mean of variable? Do you mean its name or its value to be like the sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file contains.

```
rahul@HP-EliteBook ~/Projects/Stackoverflow $ cat abc.txt 
hai am here
```

Here is the python code.It's very simple logic.

```
fo = open("abc.txt", "r+")
a = fo.read()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply! May I ask, what does "r+" mean, because I've only seen "r" and "w" for reading and writing.

Comment: @Oli Yes it is. For more reference. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm